# Fixing Open source Vulnerabilities in Java

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In our project, we have close to around 200 spring boot microservices. We are in the process of fixing the Open source vulnerabilities for these microservices. Our microservices are spring boot based and the version that is currently available is 2.3.X. While upgrading the spring boot parent version, I have the below queries

1. When upgrading the spring boot version, Is there any guiding principle based on which we need to select the version of spring boot. Currently when I checked the mvn repository for spring boot parent, the latest version available is 3.0.  Can I directly update to the latest version ? or is there any parameters to be considered while selecting the latest version
2. In our project, We also have the spring cloud dependencies, I checked the spring site(https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)  and was able to get the spring cloud version compatible with Spring boot version. I could get this only for spring cloud. Is there any site available which provides the compatibility details for the other jars like spring core etc.

Any inputs on the above is really appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Updating to latest stable version (in this case 3.0) is probably the best idea in the long run.

However, updating the major version (2.3.x -> 3.0) might be more complicated and require more work than updating to latest minor version (2.3.x -> 2.7.x). If you don't have a lot of time for this and some older version already have fixes included for those vulnerabilities it might be a viable option too. It's also possible that you have some dependencies that are not compatible with newest Spring Boot yet. But again, I believe that going for latest version is best if possible.

Spring boot parent should already contain all needed spring components versions. For example Spring Boot 2.7.3 uses spring-core:5.3.22 and you don't need to define it explicitly yourself.

Comment: I’ll just note that there is a Spring Boot blog page that helps with the upgrade process: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

Comment: @Pekinek Thanks a lot for your response.  But can you please specify the criteria based on which you specify that 3.0 is a stable version.  Because When I checked the MVN repo, looks like this was released only on 24Nov2022.  Also the usage count is not specified.

Comment: @vr3w3c9 by stable I mean official release, like 3.0. Sometimes there are version like 3.0.0-RC (release candidate) or something like 3.0.0-M4, I wouldn't use those in commercial projects.

Comment: The Spring Boot project page at https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support is the best source of information to determine which versions are currently released and supported.

Comment: I agree with @Pekinek that a major version bump (2.3.x -> 3.0.x) is more work than a minor version bump. The Spring Boot team generally recommends that you migrate to each minor version in order (2.3.x -> 2.4.x -> 2.5.x -> 2.6.x -> 2.7.x) following the releases notes for each version (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki#release-notes). Boot 3.0.x requires Java 17 and the JEE -> Jarkata namespace change, so it is definitely more work that upgrading along the 2.x line.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any guiding principle based on which we need to select the
> version of spring boot.

Generally you would select the Spring Boot version which has got the vulnerability fixed as your objective is related to security. Many times you are so behind that Spring may not provide security patches release for that minor version line that you will need to upgrade to major version but this requires lots of testing as there may be breaking changes as far as functionality is concerned. Also worth referring is [CVE vulnerability](https://www.cvedetails.com/) database for any specific vulnerability coming from transitive dependencies. You can search for a library name ( for e.g., log4j or jackson ) to check what vulnerability is there and if it has been patched in any version.

[image]